# ios Custom Player instead of default MPMoviePlayerController inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, video-streaming, nsurlprotocol

I have a custom player built using AVFoundation libraries (contains some custom streaming logic and controls). The player is not using MPMoviePlayerController classes. Inside UIWebView, there is some logic (might be the content-type) which detects if movie player needs to be launched, and by default it launches MPMoviePlayerController. As per the requirement, i need to launch a custom player that i have.

PS: Customizing MPMoviePlayerController could be an option but then i want to adhere it to the custom NSURLProtocol class, which unfortunately MPMoviePlayerController does not.

I have created a custom `NSURLProtocol` class which contains the following methods:

```
-(void)didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response {
    if (response) {
        [self.client URLProtocol: self didReceiveResponse: response cacheStoragePolicy: NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
    }
}
```

Inside this method, i am checking the content-type

```
NSString *contentType = [[response allHeaderFields] valueForKey:@"Content-Type"];
```

I get different content-types - mp4/vtt/flv, etc. I am thinking to launch the custom player from here. But what i observe is MPMoviePlayerController is launched. Is there any way to stop MPMoviePlayerController from launching, and instead launch a custom player.